# mySQL Nesting of joins N-1 and N-N

Tags: mysql, join, syntax, left-join

I'm trying to join 4 tables, two 1-N ones and one through an N-N table. Strangely mySql doesn't seem to like one of my syntaxes. Does anybody know if this is due to myOwn limitations or mySql?

This doesn't work:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableOne t1 JOIN tableTwo t2 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN N_N_tableThree t3 
            JOIN tableFour t4 ON t4.id = t3.fk_tableFour
        ON t2.id = t3.fk_tableTwo
    ON t2.id = t1.fk_tableTwo
```

While this does work

```
SELECT *
FROM tableOne t1,
tableTwo t2 LEFT OUTER JOIN N_N_tableThree t3 
        JOIN tableFour t4 ON t4.id = t3.tableFour_id
    ON t2.id = t3.tableTwo_id
WHERE t2.id = t1.tableTwo_id
```

Anybody a clue?

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this syntax instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableOne            t1 
INNER JOIN tableTwo      t2 ON t2.id = t1.fk_tableTwo
LEFT JOIN N_N_tableThree t3 ON t2.id = t3.fk_tableTwo
INNER JOIN tableFour     t4 ON t4.id = t3.fk_tableFour;
```

This will be equivalent of the second query that worked.

Because the `WHERE t2.id = t1.tableTwo_id` in the second query is actually an `INNER JOIN`<sup>**1**</sup>, which will be the same as `INNER JOIN tableTwo t2 ON t2.id = t1.fk_tableTwo` as I did. This is the old `JOIN` syntax, try to avoid it and use the ANSI SQL-92 syntax instead as I did. For more information see this:

- [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs.](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

The query you posted didn't work, because it is not the correct syntax for [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) in MySQL, you have three `ON` clauses after each others:

```
...
ON t4.id = t3.fk_tableFour
ON t2.id = t3.fk_tableTwo
ON t2.id = t1.fk_tableTwo
```

Each `JOIN` should has the join condition specified with the `ON` clause after the `JOIN` directly, if not it would a cross join<sup>**2**</sup>. But not multiple `ON`'s the way you did.

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23438/2)

---

<sup>**1:** <sup>Don't be confused with the use of `INNER JOIN` instead of `JOIN` they are the same the default `JOIN` is inner join, I just I used for readability. Also, the same thing with the `OUTER` keyword, I omit it in `LEFT JOIN` since it is optional when using `LEFT` or `RIGHT`</sup></sup>

<sup>**2:** <sup>You will find other variations of the `JOIN` syntax in MySQL in the reference page, like the `JOIN tablename` without a join condition, and others. You might need to read them.</sup></sup>

Comment: Ah, okay, that is very helpful. You just made me aware of the "new" SQL syntax. Most of my application (and myself) is in the old one.... But this makes perfect sense. Thanks for your efforts and the useful links!

Comment: Ok, but I do have another question. I'm looking into this but do have another question. What if you have a N-N table with three FK's.

Comment: @user1976489 Can you please explain how this table relates to the other tables with these three FKs? this is possible, you can `JOIN` this table more than one time with different aliases, also you can specify more than one conditions on the same `ON` as the `JOIN` condition. Feel free to edit your question explaining this with the table structure and what you are trying to do, so that I could understand it clearly as well as other users can help too.